# "null" and 0 values when trying to retrieve JavaBean properties

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've just begun doing some things with java servlets and I'm currently trying to retrieve certain values from a bean in order to show them in textboxes, so the user can modify some values later.

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="Usuario" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
```

The thing is that if I try to retrieve those values right after the execution of the login servlet / action, they show the proper values in their corresponding textfields... But, if I try to retrieve them in the correct scenario (Right after the login servlet there's a .jsp page, with some hyperlinks, and one of those is the one that takes the user to a .jsp page where he or she can modify their data) it won't work and it will show null and 0 values.

So my question is... How can I retrieve those values in the correct scenario?

Why that JavaBean loses its properties if they're stored in the session? Does it loose the values if I use hyperlinks in order to go to another .jsp page?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd check your assumptions, and consider that some containers treat HTTP and HTTPS sessions as different unless configured otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the Bean because you are probably loosing the session. You have to be sure that when you click a link you are doing a forward (request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(req,res);) or calling response.encodeURL(url) inside of response.sendRedirect(url).